# Angular2 Global Variables without import

Tags: angular, variables, global

It is possible inject one time global variables service and then use everywhere without importing into classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't you should always import but if you still wanna do that you can do it in the ugliest way like this:  `window.globalvar = "I don't recommend this but it works!"`